# Does it make sense to get a second M.Sc. while pursuing a PhD?

Tags: phd, masters

The situation: You did your B.Sc. and M.Sc. in CS with focus on subfield X1 and are now pursuing a PhD in subfield X2. There is a Masters program in subfield X2 available where you do your PhD that offers courses that allow you to advance in this subfield (which is pretty new to you).

**Does it make sense to get a second M.Sc. while pursuing a PhD if the courses of the Masters program will be beneficial to your PhD work?**
Subquestion: Do you think it is even feasible to do this based on your experience?

*The geographic context is Europe/Germany so a PhD does not include course work. A Masters (at a university of applied sciences) takes 3 semesters full time with the possibility to double that time when doing it part time.*

Comment: it makes, but it is better after phd

Comment: Not sure how this works in Germany, but in the Netherlands this is not possible if both are CS programs: subfields of CS all confer a CS degree, and you cannot obtain the same degree twice.

Comment: How about just attending the interesting lectures? A second certificate isn't going to be all that valuable, and you can save a lot of time not doing the boring parts...

Comment: @JordiVermeulen That is absolutely a point to consider because I believe it is the same for Germany. But in my specific case the Masters was a Research Master and formally in another field but I was effectively working on subfield X2 of CS.

Comment: @nengel I thought about that too. But if you do most of the lectures anyway, why not spent "a bit" of extra effort and get that second M.Sc.? Maybe I can even use a part of my PhD work and further investigate it as my Master thesis...

Comment: I like the idea of attending the important lectures that will benefit your PHD research (because that is your main goal).

Comment: Because a "bit" of extra work could be done on your PhD work and especially publishable papers. And that probably has more currency than a second masters...

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, as has already been pointed out, the Master's degree is a prerequisite for enrolling in PhD "studies." It should also be pointed out that in the German system, PhD students are *Wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter* (research *employees*), so it is expected that they would devote all of their time to research activities. Enrolling in a second master's program would run contrary to those expectations, unless you are only a part-time employee (and receive a correspondingly reduced salary). That said, it *is* possible to sit in on additional classes as a listener. (And generally this is *required* if you are coming from a foreign country!)

Comment: The PhD students in my institute all work part-time, typically ranging from 50-80% depending on the projects they work on. So I guess it would be a good idea to ask my supervisors about the workload that one can actually expect and make a decision based on that?

Comment: I don't think you need to go to the extent of enrolling for a second master's degree. Maybe you could ask if there are classes you could sit in on instead.

Answer (score -2):

Many PHd programs include a masters with them. So if you enroll in universtiy X and get Phd DD, you will earn Ms DD on your way to getting the PHd. A Phd without a dissertation is essentially a masters degree (when you compare the coursework).

Comment: This does not apply in Germany. You need to have a Master's to be allowed to start a PhD, and a PhD is _only_ the dissertation and nothing else. (In fact, you can theoretically roll up to the university with your thesis in triplicate and 3 profs who have agreed to sit on your jury, and acquire a PhD without having any previous interaction with the university.)

Comment: DD means Doctor of Divinity where I'm from. Presumably that's not what you mean?

Comment: correct I meant it as a generic variable name like XX or YY